# Why is my non-owner-drawn listbox having drawing issues after strings are added?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, atl

I'm working on my own private Windows desktop application user interface framework based on ATL which is supposed to have an almost identical class list and programming structure as AWT. (I've done almost all previous GUI development in either WTL or WinForms if I'm using C#.)

I'm having a problem when it comes to the listbox class. Every other control is able to repaint itself properly without my involvement in WM_PAINT. Listbox? Not so much. Here's how it looks:

- [Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epjyg.png)
- [After moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQAng.png)  <-- ignore the red mark at the bottom; I accidentally drew on the screenshot and didn't catch it.

Since I don't know where the actual problem is occuring, here's all the code I can think of that involves drawing. **If any other source code would help, please let me know.**

Here's my code for the WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX handler:

```
virtual LRESULT WmCtlColorListbox(MSG& msg, bool& handled)
    {
        handled = true;
        return colorControl(msg.message, reinterpret_cast<HDC>(msg.wParam), reinterpret_cast<HWND>(msg.lParam));
    }

LRESULT colorControl(UINT origMsg, HDC hdc, HWND window)
    {
        if (window == *this)
        {
            ::SetBkMode(hdc, _backMode);
            ::SetBkColor(hdc, _backColor);
            ::SetTextColor(hdc, _foreColor);
            return (LRESULT) _backBrush;
        }

        return ::SendMessage(window, origMsg, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(hdc), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(window));
    }
```

The WM_PAINT handler:

```
inline virtual LRESULT WmPaint(MSG& msg, bool& handled)
{
    OnPaint(handled);
    return handled ? 0 : 1;
}

inline virtual void OnPaint(bool& handled) { }
```

The WM_ERASEBKGND handler:

```
virtual LRESULT WmEraseBkgnd(MSG& msg, bool& handled)
{
    HDC hdcWindow = (HDC)msg.wParam;
    RECT r;
    this->GetWindowRect(&r);
    ::FillRect(hdcWindow, &r, _backBrush);
    this->Invalidate(FALSE);
    handled = true;
    return 1;
}
```

The virtual function that gets called just before ATL registers the class:

```
virtual void OnRegistering(CreationParameters& createParams)
{
    createParams.BaseClassName = WC_LISTBOX;
    createParams.WindowExStyles |= WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
}
```

I *used to* have this code inside OnPaint:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdcWindow = this->BeginPaint(&ps);

// This class automatically handles the background
// drawing for any other window
if (_backBrush == NULL)
    _backBrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(_backColor);

::FillRect(hdcWindow, &ps.rcPaint, _backBrush);
this->EndPaint(&ps);
```

but none of the text would show up, presumably because WM_PAINT was called after the text was automatically drawn...

For a bit of an explanation:

CreationParameters gets turned in to the appropriate CWndClassInfo and Register is called on it after the OnRegistering method exits.

- _backMode is a private member for the base "window" class and is either TRANSPARENT or OPAQUE; in the case of the listbox, it is currently hard-coded to be OPAQUE
- _backColor and _foreColor are private COLORREF members.
- _backBrush is a private HBRUSH which is simply a brush of _backColor and its destroyed when the control class is deconstructed.

The WM_PAINT handler simply calls an event activator (OnPaint) which does absolutely nothing; the WM_PAINT handler then calls DefWindowProc if handled is false.

I've toyed around with CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW on the class styles before creation by manually superclassing WC_LISTBOX and OR'ing in those values with horrible results (as in the fact that text added to the listbox does not appear despite being returned in LB_GETCOUNT returning the proper number of items and the listbox does not redraw *at all*) so I'm out of ideas.

Has anyone seen anything like this before and perhaps can tell me what I'm missing (or what window message I'm supposed to be handling)?

Comment: Poking around in the dark here, but I remember similar looking backgrounds when trying to fill edit boxes with a NULL_BRUSH. Maybe CreateSolidBrush returns NULL somewhere. Also, why do you validate the window on WM_ERASEBACKGROUND?

Comment: That solved PART of the problem... _backBrush was only checked for NULL *if and only if* _backColor was assigned to something different than what it was already set to... I fixed that and this is what it looks like now:

http://i.imgur.com/ix1gM.png

Comment: @pezcode: `NULL_BRUSH` is *not* equivalent to `NULL`.

Comment: Regardless of such, _backBrush was 0 every time WM_ERASEBKGND was sent so that helped narrow it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mis-matched coordinates in `WmEraseBkgnd`.  `GetWindowRect` gives screen coordinates while `FillRect` uses local coorinates.  You should either use `GetClientRect` or translate the top left and bottom right corners with `ScreenToClient`.

Comment: Egad, thanks. I can't believe I didn't catch that. I have a function called getMappedRect that calls GetClientRect or GetWindowRect depending on if the window is top-level or not. I guess I forgot to swap it out.